# CSS Issues when Adjusting Height

Tags: css

Im trying to reduce the space between the search and the thought bubble, at https://blog.fir3net.com/

However I've tried the following, but this doesn't resolve this issue.

```
.main-header-content {
  height:10px;
 }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: At 2k rep, I shouldn't have to ask, but: [mcve]. Also you've misspelled height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak your `.big-header-container .main-header .main-header-content` `padding-top` value (currently on `9.375rem`):

Example:

```
.big-header-container .main-header .main-header-content {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have padding-top at the next div:

```
padding-top: 9.375rem
```

try play with it!